# How to get different answers from different threads?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, random

To get to know threading concept better I tried to use threads in a simple program. I want to call a function 3 times which does random selection.

```
def func(arg):
    lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
    num = random.choice(lst)
    arg.append(num)
    return arg


def search(arg):
    a = func(arg)
    a = func(a)
    threads_list = []
    que = queue.Queue()
    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(func(arg1)), args=(que, a))
        t.start()
        threads_list.append(t)

    for t in threads_list:
        t.join()
    while not que.empty():
        result = que.get()
        print (result)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     lst = []
     search(lst)
```

As you can see In the third part, I used threads but I expected to get different lists ( different for the third part).
but all the threads return the same answer. 
Can anyone help me to get different lists from different threads?
I think I misunderstood the concept of multiprocessing and multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the pseudo-random number generator which `random.choice` is using is using three instances - one for each thread - and in the absence of a unique seed will produce the same pseudo-random sequence. Since no seed is provided, it may be using the system time which, depending on the precision, may be the same for all three threads.

You might try seeding the PRNG with something that will differ from thread to thread, inside the thread that invokes the PRNG. This should cause the three threads to use different seeds and give you different pseudo-random sequences.

Comment: Can you put your thoughts into practice and fix the code?